# Error: P1014 The underlying table for model `customers` does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, backend, prisma

I'm trying to execute the triggers.sql file. Below is my prisma.schema and triggers.sql file code. I've already migrate the prisma schema and generated it as well.
So when I'm running the command `npx prisma db execute --file ./prisma/triggers.sql` in the terminal I get the above error.
From the error perspective, it seems like I did not have the customers table. But when I checked it on the pg admin, it was showing there with all the required columns.

schema.prisma

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Customers {
  cust_id     Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  address     String
  phoneNumber String
  Items       Int
}

model CustomersAuditTable {
  audit_id  Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  tableName String
  rowId     Int
  operation String
  timestamp DateTime @default(now())
  userId    Int
}
```

triggers.sql

```
-- SET LOCAL current_user_id = 'malay_jeena';
-- CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pg_triggers";

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_customers() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
    $$
    BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        INSERT INTO CustomersAuditTable (tableName, rowId, operation, userId)
        VALUES ('customer', OLD.id, 'delete', current_user_id);

    ELSE IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        INSERT INTO CustomersAuditTable (tableName, rowId, operation, userId)
        VALUES ('customer', NEW.id, 'update', current_user_id);

    ELSE
        INSERT INTO CustomersAuditTable (tableName, rowId, operation, userId)
        VALUES('customer', NEW,id, 'insert', current_user_id);
    END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';


-- Creating a trigger
CREATE TRIGGER customers_audit
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON Customers
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION audit_customers();
```

Comment: Never ever use Upper case in your names, unless you want some extra work and use double quotes everywhere: Customers and "Customers" are two different tables. What table did you create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the id to cust_id in the triggers.sql file and running the

```
npx prisma db execute --file ./prisma/triggers.sql command again.
```

Additionally, you might want to uncomment the line

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pg_triggers";
```

in the triggers.sql file, as it may be required for trigger functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't select the schema (SET search_path TO --schema--;) you must reference for the full name.

```
CREATE TRIGGER --schema--.customers_audit
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON --schema--.Customers
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION --schema--.audit_customers();
```

Greetings, Alejandro